# Can someone originally granted asylum visit the home country after being granted Swedish citizenship?

Tags: asylum

I've been granted asylum in Sweden. I know that I shouldn't travel back to my home country while using a resident permit/asylum in Sweden. If I am granted Swedish citizenship, can I visit my home country? Is it possible that Swedish authorities would revoke my Swedish citizenship?

Comment: I've flagged the question and asked the moderators to move it to Expatriates. If it doesn't happen by tomorrow, you may want to ask a new question on [Expatriates.se].

Comment: What is your home country? In any case, I'd suggest you simply travel. Typically, getting back to Sweden is not a big deal.

Comment: So you have been granted both German and Swedish asylum: https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/105799/56179 ?

Comment: @AdamMichalik OP says they were granted *refugee status* in Germany, and *asylum* in Sweden. With refugees sometimes being transferred between EU countries, that's not an impossible situation.

Comment: Just a note that your Swedish citizenship would probably give you no protection in your original home country if the government there decided to take action against you while you were in the country.

Comment: @Moo countries can support their citizens in another country of nationality, but generally only with the consent of the other country, which is not obliged to allow it.  They may do so as a courtesy, however, especially if the two countries have good relations.  So "probably" may be a bit strong, but you're certainly correct that Lester should not count on it.

Comment: @phoog I said that it would probably give you no *protection* - the original citizenship country would simply deal with the person as citizen, not a foreign national and theres nothing the new citizenship country can do about it.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Swedish law](http://www.lawline.se/answers/aterkallande-av-svenskt-medborgarskap) a Swedish citizen who was born in Sweden or has ever lived in Sweden cannot lose their citizenship against their will:

> If you have been granted Swedish citizenship as per above, it cannot be revoked. No Swedish citizen who is or has been resident in Sweden may be deprived of his citizenship, even if the citizenship has been acquired on the basis of fraudulent information, a false identity or false grounds.

In Sweden, even if you lied about your identity the whole time, from arriving there as a migrant to obtaining citizenship, once you have the citizenship they ***cannot*** revoke it, ***full stop***!

So you'll be absolutely fine after becoming a Swedish citizen

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71053/discussion-on-answer-by-coke-can-someone-originally-granted-asylum-visit-the-hom).